# ant dependencies for junit in gradle issue

Tags: java, maven, gradle, junit, ant

I am getting the following error when I am trying to build my gradle file. In intellij i am not getting any issues with my code, so I am guessing that intellij doesn't have any issues with the grade configuration. However since I have to compile and build with gradle, I cannot build or run the code because of this issue.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find any version that matches org.apache:ant:[1.6.5,1.8).
  Versions that do not match:
      ant
      ant-xz
      ant-weblogic
      ant-trax
      ant-testutil
      + 32 more
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/ant/
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/
      https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/org/apache/ant/
      http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml
      http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/
      http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml
      http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/
      http://repo.akka.io/releases/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml
      http://repo.akka.io/releases/org/apache/ant/
  Required by:
      project : > org.eclipse.jdt.apt:core:3.3.0-v20070607-1200
```

I tried multiple ant and apt versions and dependency orders to try to fix this issue.

here is my current gradle build

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

// Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
apply plugin: 'application'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/"}
    maven { url "http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/"}
    maven { url "http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/"}
    maven { url "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"}
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ant', name: 'ant', version: '1.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'core', version: '3.4.2.v_883_R34x'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core', version: '3.12.3'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.annotation', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', name: 'ecj', version: '4.6.1'

    compile group: 'org.eclipse.core', name: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime', version: '3.10.0.v20140318-2214'
    compile group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.osgi.core', version: '1.4.0'
    //compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.junit', version: '3.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime', version: '3.12.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.ant', name: 'ant-launcher', version: '1.10.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ant', name: 'ant', version: '1.10.1'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.apt', name: 'core', version: '3.3.0-v20070607-1200'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.core.resources', version: '3.11.1'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.platform', name: 'org.eclipse.core.expressions', version: '3.5.100'



    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/com/bulenkov/game2048/'
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I was able to resolve the issue by using an updated version of apt.core from 3.3.0 to 3.4.100.

However this causes another resolve issue in gradle:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find any matches for org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}:[3.105.3,3.105.3] as no versions of org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform} are available.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/maven-metadata.xml
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/
      https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/
      http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/maven-metadata.xml
      http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/
      http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/maven-metadata.xml
      http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/
      http://repo.akka.io/releases/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/maven-metadata.xml
      http://repo.akka.io/releases/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}/
  Required by:
      project : > org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.junit:3.9.0 > org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.jface.text:3.11.2 > org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt:3.105.3
```

I have tested with different osgi dependencies, and cannot find this particular one in any repositories.

Comment: You have given the dependency for ant twice. Can you remove that and test again

Comment: I have removed the first ant dependency version 1.8.0 and still receive the error. I did a small test and changed the 1.10.1 version to 1.8.0 and still received the error.

Comment: I have good news and bad news for you. Good news is that I have found the issue, bad news is I am not sure why it is happening. The issue is that gradle is searching at the wrong location for the dependency. It is searching at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/maven-metadata.xml whereas it should be searching at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/maven-metadata.xml.

Comment: It sure is a start. It might be the way I have the dependency declared however it is how it appears directly at this site where I got it: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant/1.10.1 . All I suppose to do now is try to poke around for an alternative or see if anyone else can figure the repo issue out.

Comment: This dependency is specified here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/apt/core/3.3.0-v20070607-1200/core-3.3.0-v20070607-1200.pom, and this entry is invalid. I guess they build their artifacts in a specific, non-standard way. No idea how this dependency is resolved.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by updating the apt.core version to 3.4.100, however the problem was now extended to a different dependency. I will update the question.